# Find gateway of VLAN on Linux

Tags: linux-networking, vlan, gateway

I have a Linux box on a network where the network has several VLANs. Of course, the Linux box is on VLAN 1 (the LAN) and I know how to get the default gateway on the LAN using "netstat -rn" and parsing the results. But I need to find a way to get the default gateway on the other VLANs as well, eg for VLAN 3 (192.168.3.0/24) I would expect the gateway to be something like 192.168.3.1. Is there any Linux command that can give me the gateway on other VLANs if my Linux box is not on that VLAN?

Comment: You would be guessing, unless you'ld have a concrete way of querying for network specifics (AWS API, openvswitch, libvirt, ...). Can you tell us more? Where would one operate these networks, is there any API? If guessing is good enough, some sed replacing your the last characters from your subnet should give you your gateway.

Comment: Why would there be any reason for the Linux box to be aware of any other VLANs?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why not just listen for RA Packets?